# I have Linux Ubuntu installed on my PC, but when i put my other harddrive with windows it doesn't

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, boot

My PC has LinuxUbuntu, when I insert my  other HDD with windows it doesn't boot, when I go to bios there is no windows boot manager there is only "ubuntu" under boot options. How can I be able to boot my windows HDD and also be able to boot my Ubuntu HDD